# Can my phone act as a WiFi access point without mobile data?

Tags: wi-fi, ad-hoc-networks, samsung-captivate

I have an old (Galaxy S1-class) phone running a custom ICS ROM.  It has a pay-as-you-go mobile SIM without data.

I also have a bunch of kids with iPads that want to play Minecraft together.  As far as I can tell, I can't get the iPad to make an ad-hoc wifi network on its own.  If I had mobile data, I could turn on the Mobile Hotspot feature, connect all the iPads to the phone.  I think if I did this now, though, my SIM would be charged for any stray Internet requests that are accidentally made.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
'adb shell setprop SimCheck.disable 1'
```

This will disable sim check while turning on WiFi tethering.

Comment: Is there an equivalent syntax from the Terminal Emulator on the phone itself? (I don't have a computer handy at the moment, but I do have Terminal Emulator)

Comment: Also!  Would I have to take the SIM *out* to make sure it doesn't try to charge for data? Right now I just set the "mobile data" switch to OFF.

Comment: can't you enter this command in terminal emulator.?are you able to turn on tethering with mobile data off?

Comment: I was sure it wouldn't work, but I was able to turn off wi-fi, turn off mobile data, then turn on the hotspot.  Thanks, @Rilwan! (Do you maybe want to make a separate answer for that, then I can accept it?)

Comment: @james: which way you enable tethering now? simcheck disable or turn off mobiledata & Wifi then turn on tethering? By default turning on tethering should disable WiFi. So i thought just turning off mobiledata should be enough for you. Thanks anyway!

Comment: As for the terminal emulator: I would try just skipping the `adb shell` from the command (which does nothing else but opening a shell on the Android device, which the terminal emulator does itself), i.e. executing simply `setprop SimCheck.disable 1`.